# Remove Chrome DevTools Workspace Folder

Tags: google-chrome, directory, google-chrome-devtools, workspace

I've by mistake added the wrong folder to my Workspaces in Chrome DevTools.

How do I remove it?

[image: A screenshot of my current Workspace arrangement.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh wait… found the solution.

When you hover over the box there’s an ‘x’ you can click.

Sadly I couldn’t click this ‘x’ because it was being blocked by the path.

By resizing your window you can very exactly position your mouse to just hover over the ‘x’ but not the path. Very buggy.

Answer (score 11):

In order to find the workspaces that you have configured you need to go into the `Customize and Control DevTools` menu (3 vertical dots at the top right of the console > Settings > Workspace).

Then the workspaces that you have added are listed and you can remove them using the `X` in the list.

I had problems when I added my whole workspace with all my projects in it to chrome. This resulted in the console freezing for a few minutes every time I opened it.

Comment: This works, while in my case removing a folder by context menu in Sources tab doesn't.